# Matching Records in R based on Column Difference

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
df1<-data.frame(ID_NUMBER = c(7160015,22695229,22695230,7160016,7160017,22695198,7160018,22695199,7160019,22695200,7160020,22695232,7160030,22697153,22697158,7162962,22698039,22698041,7162964) 
, CalNumber = c(9662.37,9662.45,9663.41,9663.44,9665.97,9666.11,9667.04,9667.1,9667.87,9668.01,9668.74,9668.79,9868.2, 72719.75,72723.21,99774,99774.03,99776.11,99776.13)
,Inspection_Date = c('11/13/2009','10/8/2014','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','10/8/2014','11/13/2009'))
```

I am trying to match the 10/08/2014 records to the 11/13/2009 records based on the closest proximity to CalNumber (which the absolute difference that is <=1).  The records are ordered by CalNumber.    The smallest 11/13/2009 record match could be the before or after the 10/08/2014 record.  Once a 10/08/2014 record is matched to the closest 11/13/2009 record, then that 11/13/2009 record is not considered for anymore matches.

Sorry if it is confusing.  Hopefully this explains it better.  This is what the final result set would look like.

```
df1<-data.frame(ID_NUMBER = c(7160015,22695229,22695230,7160016,7160017,22695198,7160018,22695199,7160019,22695200,7160020,22695232,7160030,22697153,22697158,7162962,22698039,22698041,7162964) 
, CalNumber = c(9662.37,9662.45,9663.41,9663.44,9665.97,9666.11,9667.04,9667.1,9667.87,9668.01,9668.74,9668.79,9868.2, 72719.75,72723.21,99774,99774.03,99776.11,99776.13)
,Inspection_Date = c('11/13/2009','10/8/2014','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','10/8/2014','11/13/2009','10/8/2014','10/8/2014','11/13/2009')
,Diff = c(NA,0.08,0.03,NA,NA,0.14,NA,0.06,NA,0.14,NA,0.05,NA, NA,NA,NA,0.03,0.02,NA)
,MatchID = c(NA,7160015,7160016,NA,NA,7160017,NA,7160018,NA,7160019,NA,7160020,NA, NA,NA,NA,7162962,7162964,NA))
```

The final result set has 2 additional columns.  Diff (abs(CalNumber)<=1), which is the abs difference of the closest record based on CalNumber. MatchID, which is the corresponding ID_Number that was the closest record.  If the 10/08/2014 does not have a <=1 match, then it is left blank.  All 11/13/2009 MatchID columns are blank.  The MatchID is only populated for 10/08/2014 records with 11/13/2009 closest matches.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What code have you tried to create the new columns Diff and MatchID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm relatively new to `data.table` so bear with me:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(df1)
dt2 <- copy(dt1)

setnames(dt2, c("ID_NUMBER", "CalNumber", "Inspection_Date"), c("ID_NUMBER2", "CalNumber2", "Inspection_Date2"))

dt2[dt1,
    .(ID_NUMBER,
      CalNumber,
      Inspection_Date,
      Diff = abs(CalNumber - CalNumber2),
      MatchID = ID_NUMBER2),
    on = .(Inspection_Date2 > Inspection_Date),
    allow.cartesian = TRUE
    ][,
      .SD[which.min(ifelse(is.na(Diff), Inf, Diff))],
      by = .(ID_NUMBER, CalNumber, Inspection_Date)
      ][,
        .(ID_NUMBER,
          CalNumber,
          Inspection_Date,
          Diff = ifelse(Diff > 1, NA, Diff),
          MatchID = ifelse(Diff > 1, NA, MatchID))
        ]

    ID_NUMBER CalNumber Inspection_Date Diff MatchID
 1:   7160015   9662.37      11/13/2009   NA      NA
 2:  22695229   9662.45       10/8/2014 0.08 7160015
 3:  22695230   9663.41       10/8/2014 0.03 7160016
 4:   7160016   9663.44      11/13/2009   NA      NA
 5:   7160017   9665.97      11/13/2009   NA      NA
 6:  22695198   9666.11       10/8/2014 0.14 7160017
 7:   7160018   9667.04      11/13/2009   NA      NA
 8:  22695199   9667.10       10/8/2014 0.06 7160018
 9:   7160019   9667.87      11/13/2009   NA      NA
10:  22695200   9668.01       10/8/2014 0.14 7160019
11:   7160020   9668.74      11/13/2009   NA      NA
12:  22695232   9668.79       10/8/2014 0.05 7160020
13:   7160030   9868.20      11/13/2009   NA      NA
14:  22697153  72719.75       10/8/2014   NA      NA
15:  22697158  72723.21       10/8/2014   NA      NA
16:   7162962  99774.00      11/13/2009   NA      NA
17:  22698039  99774.03       10/8/2014 0.03 7162962
18:  22698041  99776.11       10/8/2014 0.02 7162964
19:   7162964  99776.13      11/13/2009   NA      NA
```

The copying of `dt1` was because I had issues referencing columns during the self join. I also suspect some of the operations can be consolidated, so the input of other users is very welcome.

#### Logic:

- First set of brackets performs a left inequality joins of `dt1` with `dt2`, calculates the `Diff` variable. `data.table`'s left join syntax is a little weird, but what it's doing is taking all rows from `dt2` that match what is specified in the `on` argument
- Second set of brackets gets the records matching a minimum value within a group. Here the value is a slightly altered `Diff` variable (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52838298/matching-records-in-r-based-on-column-difference/52839592?noredirect=1#comment92597996_52839592) post I used for help)
- Third brackets assign `NA` to `Diff` and `MatchID` values where the min `Diff` was above 1

Comment: I don't understand the OP's logic, but a rolling join somehow works also: `df1[!is.na(Diff), v := df1[!.BY, on=names(.BY)][.SD, on=.(CalNumber), roll="nearest", x.ID_NUMBER], by=ID_NUMBER]`

Comment: @Zach --Logic works great!  Do you mind explaining the logic?  Thanks again!

Comment: what is this part doing:  .SD[which.min(ifelse(is.na(Diff), Inf, Diff))],
      by = .(ID_NUMBER, CalNumber, Inspection_Date) ....sorry but im very new to R

Comment: Updated post with some logic. I'm not exactly sure where @Frank's rolling join fits in here, but it's likely something more clever than what I'm doing.

Comment: i saw the cartesian join, do you think it will work well when the recordset is a lot larger?  i think the largest i have is about 100K.

Comment: @Frank where would the rolling join go?

Comment: `allow.cartesian` doesn't result in a full cross-join, for `data.table`, it just allows for a join to result in a set larger than both the number of rows of both datasets combined. Check out `?data.table`, their documentation is pretty good. For your dataset, whether or not it work is a function of the data makeup (e.g., how many 10/8 values there are vs 11/13 values) and your machine, so I can't really say.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @zack's answer, I think I now get what the OP is doing. To find nearest match, usually a rolling join can be used:

```
setDT(df1)
df1[Inspection_Date == "10/8/2014", c("md", "mid") := 
  df1[Inspection_Date == "11/13/2009"][.SD, on=.(CalNumber), roll="nearest", 
    .(abs(x.CalNumber - i.CalNumber), x.ID_NUMBER)
  ]
]

# oh, and then wipe it out if diff > 1
df1[md > 1, c("md", "mid") := NA]


    ID_NUMBER CalNumber Inspection_Date Diff MatchID   md     mid
 1:   7160015   9662.37      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
 2:  22695229   9662.45       10/8/2014 0.08 7160015 0.08 7160015
 3:  22695230   9663.41       10/8/2014 0.03 7160016 0.03 7160016
 4:   7160016   9663.44      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
 5:   7160017   9665.97      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
 6:  22695198   9666.11       10/8/2014 0.14 7160017 0.14 7160017
 7:   7160018   9667.04      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
 8:  22695199   9667.10       10/8/2014 0.06 7160018 0.06 7160018
 9:   7160019   9667.87      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
10:  22695200   9668.01       10/8/2014 0.14 7160019 0.14 7160019
11:   7160020   9668.74      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
12:  22695232   9668.79       10/8/2014 0.05 7160020 0.05 7160020
13:   7160030   9868.20      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
14:  22697153  72719.75       10/8/2014   NA      NA   NA      NA
15:  22697158  72723.21       10/8/2014   NA      NA   NA      NA
16:   7162962  99774.00      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
17:  22698039  99774.03       10/8/2014 0.03 7162962 0.03 7162962
18:  22698041  99776.11       10/8/2014 0.02 7162964 0.02 7162964
19:   7162964  99776.13      11/13/2009   NA      NA   NA      NA
```

I am hard-coding specific dates based on OP's...

> I am trying to match the 10/08/2014 records to the 11/13/2009 records based on the closest proximity to CalNumber (which the absolute difference that is <=1).

... while zack's answer more generally compares dates. (Note that you should use a proper date format for this, eg `df1[, Inspection_Date := as.IDate(Inspection_Date, "%m/%d/%Y")]`)

---

*How it works*

The key part is a join `x[i, on=, roll=, j]` of the 2009 subset `x = df1[Inspection_Date == "11/13/2009"]` and the 2014 subset `i = .SD = df1[Inspection_Date == "10/8/2014"]` based on conditions in `on=` and `roll=`.

Inside the `j` of `x[i, on=, roll=, j]`, prefixes `x.*` and `i.*` can be used to disambiguate common column names.

Comment: If I wanted to Add another column to join on, where would that go?  The nearest roll is per group. I tried by adding on to the join like this: .SD, on=.(CalNumber , x.Column1 == i.Column2), but it didn't work.  Do you know where I would add the one additional join.

Comment: @yanci The roll always uses the last column in on=, so you should add other columns before CalNumber.

Comment: I get Column(s) [x.Column1] not found in x'... it is part of the dataset.  I moved it .SD, on=.(x.Column1 == i.Column2, CalNumber )  thanks!

Comment: I modified to SD, on=.(Column1 == Column2, CalNumber ) and it worked.  how does it know how to differentiate the columns.. it worked though

Comment: @yanci Oh, forgot to mention, the left-hand var is interpreted as from x; and the right-hand from i already. (See `?data.table` for other syntax stuff)